# How to add new div section in ko template(Checkoutpage payment section) in magento 2

Tags: checkout, template, magento2.2.2

I wish to add one div section on the checkout page(payment section) to add a custom message. How do I add it in below KO template
**Magento/SalesRule/view/frontend/web/template/payment/discount.html.** 
Please provide me a solution.

[image]

I need to show message in after apply discount button
I have added a div in Magento/SalesRule/view/frontend/web/template/payment/discount.html. But It is falied to show the div section in checkout page(payment section)

Comment: Explain what you have tried and what errors you are facing.

Comment: I wish to add a custom message in new div section in checkout page

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: Have you run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` after making changes in the HTML file?

Comment: yes, but no change occurs

Comment: Its is because of cache issue, Now works fine